# automake/gnu make dealing with directories in patterned rules

Tags: gnu-make, automake

When I create a patterned rule, or some other custom rule, I need to be able to deal with the target directory not existing. This is for when the project is being built in a directory other than the source directory itself.

For example:

```
%.out: %.in
   gen_file.sh $< > $@
```

The problem is when somebody specifies a path in the dependency:

```
some_target: some/path/sample.out
```

This fails because the `some/path` directory doesn't exist.

Is there a standard way of getting this directory to be created?

*NOTE: I'm trying to use mkdir now, but having issues with getting the directory name as opposed to the filename. Probably just an escaping issue. Update: Got this to work with `@mkdir -p $(shell dirname $@)` This isn't likely portable.*

Comment: Your `mkdir -p` solution looks fine to me, unless you are willing to tackle the root cause (don't name targets in nonexistent directories).

Comment: There is no root cause. I'm building in a different directory than the source, which is supposed to be supported. The standard targets, like "%.o: %.c" must somehow also create the directory.

Comment: so `some_target: $(top_srcdir)/some/path/sample.out` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `automake` does this is by making anything that could depend on a non-existent directory depend on a target `some/dir/.dirstamp`. The following pattern rule should cover that:

```
%/.dirstamp:
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        touch $@
```

Note also the use of `$(@D)` to get the directory part of `$@`. That means you don't have to use `$(shell dirname $@)` (or the GNU Make built-in `$(dir $@)`). See [the GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) for more.

Comment: Can I actually use this rule?  That is, can I just make something depend on `some/path/.dirstamp`, or this more of an internal rule not guaranteed to exist.  `$(@D)` is certainly useful.

Comment: It's not built-in to GNUmake and it's something of an implementation detail of automake. If you're hand-writing your makefiles you can define it yourself. If you're using the autotools, you can use `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS` to ensure the required directories exist.